# While loop with user input validation to fill array, then search array for largest number.

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop

I am working on a program that will accept user input to fill an array and then quit when the user enters q. Next the array is passed to a function that finds the largest value in the array. My program seems like it would work, but I believe that user input for the array is incorrect and I am not sure how to solve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 30

int maxnum(int userarray[], int maxx);


int main()
{
    int i;
    int nums[SIZE];
    int largest;


    printf("Type integer numbers (up to 30), followed by q to quit:\n");

    while(scanf("%d", &nums[i]) == 1)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
            //blank
        }
    }

    largest = maxnum(nums, SIZE);
    printf("The largest number is: %d\n", largest);

    return 0;
}

int maxnum(int userarray[], int maxx)
{
    int i;
    int maxnumber; 

    maxnumber = userarray[0];

    for(i = 1; i < maxx; i++)
    {
        if(maxnumber < userarray[i])
        {
            maxnumber = userarray[i];
        }
    }

    return maxnumber; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First `i` is unitialized.

Then your inner `for` loop is strange (why someone would do that??) and sets `i` to `SIZE` in the end, which is not good.

I don't give more details, but the value of `i` is trash all the time because of those 2 mistakes it should be:

```
int i = 0;

while((i<SIZE) && (scanf("%d", &nums[i]) == 1))
{
    i++;
}
```

so you read one by one, and protect against array out of bounds by the second condition.

After that you're passing `NUMS`

```
largest = maxnum(nums, SIZE);
```

whereas the array could contain fewer valid values. Just pass

```
largest = maxnum(nums, i);
```

Comment: how true!! fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another solution for your problem.**

In **main()** function

```
int n,i=0;
  while(scanf("%d",&n) == 1){
    nums[i++] = n;
  }
n = maxnum(nums, i);
printf("The largest number is: %d\n", n);
```

**Note :** Initialize the value of **i=0**, Then input and update **nums[]** array

In **maxnum()** function

```
for(i = 0; i < maxx; i++)    {
  if(maxnumber < userarray[i]){
      maxnumber = userarray[i];
  }
}
```

**Note:** Start **i=0** and find the max mumber and return the value